# dotnet 5.4 - System.IO

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to check if a File exists from a ASP.NET MVC 6 application. But I'm having trouble adding the `System.IO` dependency for `dotnet 5.4`. I'm getting a compile error when using `File.exists` even though `System.IO` is imported without a problem.

Warning when calling the method:
[image]
compile error:
[image]

After installing System.IO from Nuget my project.json was updated to:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
  }
```

I tried modifying it to the following but it didn't fix the issue either:

```
 "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
        "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You never said what is the problem.

Comment: The application does not compile because "File" is not available for the .NET platform 5.4 (see screenshot).

Comment: Are you using the core CLR?

Comment: @Reinard Please add that information in your question. From screenshot it's not clear what is the problem. Also add what is the exact error message you're getting. That will help answers to help you.

Comment: Use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to search for missing packages and that will tell which you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to [`System.IO.FileSystem`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/4.0.1-beta-23516) which includes the `File` type.

Comment: fixed the issue, thanks. My fault for not checking the correct version of documentation

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the `System.IO` references and doing the following through NuGet:
`Install-Package System.IO.FileSystem`

Comment: Modified it, cleaned solution, restored packages, etc but no difference.

Comment: Edits made, try again.